# check for a word in a file, then add a word at the end of the same line

Tags: linux, unix, nagios

I have to add 2 IP addresses in a cfg file in 70 linux machines.

This is the plan. 
Search for a word called "allowed_hosts" in /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg, then append these 2 IPs at the end of the the same line of that file.

Could some one help me doing this through just one command?

If i can do this in all other 69 machines, by logging in to a single machine, then it would be so great!!

Comment: Anything you have done yourself to show us you've mad an effort?

Comment: I am not very good at linux, still I have tried this
echo "10.3.210.63,10.3.210.64" >>/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg
But it is going to the last line of the file. 

Then I tried echo "10.3.210.63,10.3.210.64" >>cat /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg | grep -i allowed_hosts /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg

But Nothing happened...

Comment: @Naruto : Sorry, I am not very good at linux, still I have tried this 

echo "10.3.210.63,10.3.210.64" >>/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg. But it is going to the last line of the file. Then I tried - echo "10.3.210.63,10.3.210.64" >>cat /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg | grep -i allowed_hosts /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg 
But Nothing happened... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed '/allowed_host/s/$/ 1.2.3.4 5.6.7.8/'`

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. But am getting the below error.

xxx@abc.com$ sed '/allowed_hosts/s/$/ 10.3.210.63,10.3.210.64' /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg  
sed: -e expression #1, char 43: unterminated `s' command


xxx@abc.com$ sed '/allowed_hosts/$/ 10.3.210.63,10.3.210.64' /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg  
sed: -e expression #1, char 16: unknown command: `$'

Comment: You are missing the `/s/`.

Comment: But I tried both.

sed '/allowed_hosts/s/$/ 10.3.23.11,10.3.23.37/' /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg

This didnt give me error and shown what /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg has(same as cat), but didnt add anything to the preferred file...

Comment: If you wish to use sed to modify a file in-place, you need to use `-i`.